# How to hide tags in wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide posts containing some tags on the Home Page.

I can do this for the category. I add it to the function.php file;

```
<?php
function burakisciKAT($query) {
    if ($query->is_home) {
        if (!$query->get('cat'))  {
            $query->set('cat','-8');
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','burakisciKAT');
?>
```

How do I make a tag?

Comment: Modify the homepage loop and edit the query by filtering for the tag. WordPress has a section on this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress there is a argument parameter to exclude specific tags.
The argument parameter is **'tag__not_in' => array()** //array of tags ids.
So try to replace your code with my code ,and edit the tag's ids array  *array( 37, 47 )*.

```
<?php
function burakisciKAT($query) {
    if ($query->is_home) {
        if (!$query->get('cat'))  {
            $query->set('cat','-8');
        }
        $query->set('tag__not_in',array( 37, 47 )); //ARRAY OF TAG'S IDS WHICH YOU WANT TO EXCLUDE 
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','burakisciKAT');
?>
```

Then let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: I know this is an old post now, but I've just tried the above code on my site and it doesn't appear to work. A similar version that excludes a category id does, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

This condition (inside the loop) prevents posts to be displayed which have a tag that is listed in that array (must be inside php tags):

```
[... loop start ... ]
  if(!has_tag( array( 'people', 'animals', 'plants' ) ) {
    [... echoing header, content etc. ...]
  }
[... loop end ... ]
```